Response caching does not respect Cache-Control header in WSO2 API Manager
When using API response caching [1] in the WSO2 API Manager v4.1.0, the Cache-Control header is not respected and the response is still fetched from the cache.
I updated the velocity_template and api_product_template files to enable the cache control in following manner and tried different combinations, but it was not successful.
velocity_template.xml
<cache scope="per-host" collector="false" timeout="$!responseCacheTimeOut">
    <protocol type="HTTP">
        <methods>GET</methods>
        <responseCodes>2[0-9][0-9]</responseCodes>
        <enableCacheControl>true</enableCacheControl>
        <hashGenerator>org.wso2.carbon.mediator.cache.digest.HttpRequestHashGenerator</hashGenerator>
    </protocol>
    <implementation type="memory" maxSize="500"/>
    <onCacheHit>
        <property name="api.analytics.cacheHit" value="true" scope="default"/>
        <respond/>
    </onCacheHit>
</cache>

api_product_template.xml
<cache scope="per-host" collector="false" timeout="$!responseCacheTimeOut">
    <protocol type="HTTP">
        <methods>GET</methods>
        <responseCodes>2[0-9][0-9]</responseCodes>
        <enableCacheControl>true</enableCacheControl>
        <headersToIncludeInHash>Cache-Control</headersToIncludeInHash>
        <hashGenerator>org.wso2.carbon.mediator.cache.digest.HttpRequestHashGenerator</hashGenerator>
    </protocol>
    <implementation type="memory" maxSize="500"/>
</cache>

Even though the enableCacheControl is set to true, and the APIs are invoked with Cache-Control header values such as no-store, max-age=0, or no-cache, the cache mediator does not adhere this.
How can I ensure the response caching respects Cache-control? or is there any other mechanism to fetch non-cached data?
Thank you in advance!
[1] https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/4.1.0/deploy-and-publish/deploy-on-gateway/api-gateway/response-caching/

I also found this Git issue: https://github.com/wso2/product-apim/issues/11679
